# Vimeo API - Request for all videos by user works, but does not return video_ids

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Using vimeo's current API 3.0, and [the stock Vimeo php library](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php), my authenticated GET request for all videos by a certain user returns all the user's videos, but the data array for each video in the list does not include the basic video ID field anywhere.

It is not returned **even when you do the call via [Vimeo's API playground](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/)**. This leads me to believe it is simply not returned in the data. I'm not filtering any of the fields, although I would like to eventually. The below example shows part of the complete dataset returned via the playground, and trust me there is no video_id field anywhere in there.

The video ID is the unique identifier for any video on Vimeo, and it can be found in the URI, of course. But it is not returned as a separate field in the complete serialized data for each video, as one might expect. The title and description fields, for example, are returned, but these are not unique identifiers for the video itself, only the ID is.

It's hard to believe one has to get the ID by trimming the URI, or the link.

I need the ID so I can tell which videos are already embedded in my website, and if any videos by the Vimeo user are new.

Here's a sample of returned data from a call. The first video data begins after the opening of the "data" array - the video_id is obviously 173001812, as you can tell from the URI. There are plenty more fields below the "embed" array, but there is no field for the video_id.

The old "Advanced" API did return the ID.

```html
HTTP/1.1 200
Last-Modified: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 02:10:18 GMT
X-RateLimit-Limit: 500
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 499
X-RateLimit-Reset: 2016-07-14T06:02:35+00:00
Content-Type: application/vnd.vimeo.video+json
Host: api.vimeo.com

{
    "total": 176,
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 25,
    "paging": {
        "next": "/users/468130/videos?page=2",
        "previous": null,
        "first": "/users/468130/videos?page=1",
        "last": "/users/468130/videos?page=8"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "uri": "/videos/173001812",
            "name": "K2 Electric Foil Test 10R",
            "description": "June 30, 2016.",
            "link": "https://vimeo.com/173001812",
            "duration": 28,
            "width": 1920,
            "language": null,
            "height": 1080,
            "embed": {
                "uri": "/presets/212874",
                "html": "<iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/173001812?badge=0&autopause=0&player_id=0\" width=\"1920\" height=\"1080\" frameborder=\"0\" title=\"K2 Electric Foil Test 10R\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>",
                "buttons": {
                    "like": false,
                    "watchlater": false,
                    "share": false,
                    "embed": false,
                    "hd": false,
                    "fullscreen": true,
                    "scaling": true
                },
                "logos": {
                    "vimeo": false,
                    "custom": {
```

Comment: do you have a code example?

Comment: hi crazymatt, i'm making the GET call using Vimeo's stock library. the same results can be tested and obtained in their playground, see edits above. even in the vimeo API playground, the video_id field is not returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work for Vimeo...

This is correct, the numeric video ID is not returned as a standalone value anywhere. This is by design.

The unique identifier is actually the video's URI which is keyed to "uri" in the JSON response.

Comment: Thanks Alfie for clarifying. This will be a little inconvenient for my exisiting site, since the 100 or so existing videos for the last few years *are* identified by the numeric video ID. Right-trimming the URI won't work - some of the videos have URI's like "/videos/171651688:16d576044f", but in my DB it's identified as "171651688". I guess i can to a preg search for a long string of only digits, but ugh... it's that numeric ID that has so far identified the content.

Comment: It would sure be nice to have that one field back, among so much data! it seems there must be other use cases like mine.

Comment: Some videos can not be referenced by their video id alone, such as the example you provided (/videos/171651688:16d576044f). /videos/171651688 will fail, because you don't have the additional information required. There are many other videos that work like this (in channels, albums, groups, etc) so id becomes useless as a reference, hence the inclusion of URI.

Comment: Dashron- got it, thanks. However - that is what the URI field is for, I'm asking for a separate video_id field for my own reference, not to build a URI. I'm sure the last part of the URI references something important like a cut or color balance, but as embedded in my site maybe I only need one version of "Dave catching a wave, July 2 2016" so I don't need the more specific info. With all the non-specific data ("title", "author") you guys make available for every video, it doesn't seem like much to add. It's useful reference info for the user.

Comment: What dashron is saying is that the uri is that value. It can be considered the "video ID". It just happens to be a string that looks like a path. Instead of a number. At the end of the day it's just a value. Do you need an integer specifically?

Comment: An integer is the only thing that provides an apples-to-apples comparison field with the 100+ existing embeds, which use the old ID field as the only identifying meta. Without that, my option is to delete all embeds, and re-embed them with the new URI field as the comparison meta, rather than the simple ID. It will work but it seems like unnecessary breakage.